# Access files stored in the shared storage on Android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I copy a file from USB to my SamSung S7 tablet using My Files app shipped with my tablet. I can find this file under /data using My Files app.
I believe this file is stored in the shared external storage. As pointed in
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

I need Android Storage Access Framework to access this file.

I want to access this file with my own app and I need to know the URL. What's the URL look like?

Thanks.

YL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file URL looks like this in Android and you can use this type of URL to access files:

> `file:///path/to/foo.txt`

- `file://` is used to refer to URL pointing to a world-readable file.
- You can get **path** to directory from one of these `getExternalFilesDir() or getExternalCacheDir() or getExternalMediaDirs()`. Hence, `getExternalStorageDirectory` is deprecated and no longer recommended for use. ([Read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context))
- Lastly, make sure you have made permission to access: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: @EnJ I am glad I could be of help. Please accept my answer if it was helpful. Thank you!